# Most dynamic way to setup collision bounds for player in Libgdx?

Tags: java, libgdx, 2d, collision, game-physics

I have a player sprite of 64 x 64 pixels. The actual pixels of the image are about half of the image width (32 px), and in the center. What is the easiest way to setup collision bounds using 4 rectangles for top, bottom, left, and right? Should I manually hardcode the rectangle positions like this? :

```
public Rectangle getBounds() {
    return new Rectangle(pos.x + currentAnim.getCurrentFrame().getWidth() * 1 / 3, pos.y, currentAnim.getCurrentFrame().getWidth() - currentAnim.getCurrentFrame().getWidth() * 2 / 3, currentAnim.getCurrentFrame().getHeight() / 10);
}

public Rectangle getTopBounds() {
    float width = getBounds().getWidth();
    float height = getBounds().getHeight() / 2;
    return new Rectangle(getBounds().x + .016f, getBounds().y + currentAnim.getCurrentFrame().getHeight() - height, width - .032f, height);
}
```

Is this the best way to go about things? I feel like it's too hard coded, but can't see any other solutions. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why would you want four rectangle bounds for a rectangle sized image? Can't you just return the rectangle itself as bounding rect? Otherwise you could just return two points for each bound (which form a line).